# PdfBox 2.0.0 write text at given postion in a page

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have just passed from PdfBox 1.8 to 2.0.0 and there are quite significant differences. Before to write a text on an existing pdf page I used drawString. In 2.0.0 draw string is deprecated but showText does not work in a block text.

My code in 1.8:

```
 contentStream.beginText()
 contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(250, 665)
 contentStream.drawString("1  2 3 4 5 6    7  8  9   1 0")
 contentStream.endText()
```

My code in 2.0

```
  PDDocument newPdf=null
  newPdf=PDDocument.load(sourcePdfFile)
  PDPage firstPage=newPdf.getPage(0)
  PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(newPdf, firstPage, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND,true,true)
  contentStream.setFont(pdfFont, fontSize)
  contentStream.beginText()
  contentStream.lineTo(200,685)
  contentStream.showText("John")
  contentStream.endText()
```

But it does not working...

Anyone has any idea about how can I write text as in 1.8

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`LineTo` is to draw a line. What you want is `newLineAtOffset` (the deprecation notice of moveTextPositionByAmount says so), so your code is like this:

```
  PDDocument newPdf = PDDocument.load(sourcePdfFile);
  PDPage firstPage=newPdf.getPage(0);
  PDFont pdfFont= PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;
  int fontSize = 14;
  PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(newPdf, firstPage, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND,true,true);
  contentStream.setFont(pdfFont, fontSize);
  contentStream.beginText();
  contentStream.newLineAtOffset(200,685);
  contentStream.showText("John");
  contentStream.endText();
  contentStream.close(); // don't forget that one!
```

Comment: What if I want to add two lines? e.g. contentStream.newLineAtOffset(200,685);
  contentStream.showText("John"); contentStream.newLineAtOffset(200,785);
  contentStream.showText("Doe") ? Do I have all the time to do beginText() and endText() ?

Comment: It does not work if I am doing like this:contentStream.beginText()
        contentStream.newLineAtOffset(200,685);
        contentStream.showText("John")

        contentStream.newLineAtOffset(250, 665);
        contentStream.showText("1  2 3 4 5 6    7  8  9   1 0") contentStream.endText()

Comment: Sorry, the values are relative. So for you, it would be contentStream.newLineAtOffset(0, -20); . Other possibility: look at the EmbeddedFonts.java example in the source code download. Btw "It does not work" is not very specific. I can only guess that you meant "the second line didn't appear".

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for code to add multiple line statement in PDF at desired position 
like this  

this is line first
this is line second
this is line third

then you need use

```
    //to load PDF where you 
    PDDocument pdDocument = PDDocument.load(new File(resourceBundle.getString("F:\PDF\loki.pdf")));
    //get the page where you want to write code,for first page you need to use 0
    PDPage firstPage = pdDocument.getPage(0);

    //you can load new font if required, by using `ttf` file for that font
    PDFont pdfFont = PDType0Font.load(pdDocument, 
new File(resourceBundle.getString("F:\PDF\data\verdana.ttf")));

    int fontSize = 9;
    //PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND this part is must if you want just add new data in exsitnig one
    PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(pdDocument, pdDocument.getPage(0),
            PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true, true);

    contentStream.setFont(PDType0Font.load(pdDocument, new File(resourceBundle.getString("pdfFont"))), 9);

    //for first Line
    contentStream.beginText();
    //For adjusting location of text on page you need to adjust this two values
    contentStream.newLineAtOffset(200,685);
    contentStream.showText("this is line first");
    contentStream.endText();

    //for second line
    contentStream.beginText();
    contentStream.newLineAtOffset(200,685);
    contentStream.showText("this is line second");
    contentStream.endText();

    //for  third line
    contentStream.beginText();
    contentStream.newLineAtOffset(200,685);
    contentStream.showText("this is line third");
    contentStream.endText();
    //and so on.

    //at last you need to close the document to save data
    contentStream.close(); 
   //this is for saving your PDF you can save with new name 
   //or you can replace existing one by giving same name 
    pdDocument.save(resourceBundle.getString("F:\PDF\lokiTheKing.pdf"));
```

Comment: You don't need to do this. You can use newLineAtOffset, it's just relative to the last offset. See @Tilman Hausherr and comment above.