# Add invisible text to pdf using python or java to make searchable pdf

Tags: java, python

I have a PDF containing images (scanned document). I also have text extracted from each page with its location. I need add this text into original page behind the images to make original PDF searchable.

I am looking for any open source library preferably using python or java that can help achieve it.

Link below talks about pdfbox but not how to write it under the image
[PdfBox 2.0.0 write text at given postion in a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36449776/pdfbox-2-0-0-write-text-at-given-postion-in-a-page)

```
PDDocument newPdf = PDDocument.load(sourcePdfFile);
PDPage firstPage=newPdf.getPage(0);
PDFont pdfFont= PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;
int fontSize = 14;
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new 
PDPageContentStream(newPdf, 
firstPage, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND,true,true);
contentStream.setFont(pdfFont, fontSize);
contentStream.beginText();
contentStream.newLineAtOffset(200,685);
contentStream.showText("John");
contentStream.endText();
contentStream.close(); // don't forget that one!
```

Is it possible to use pdfbox like above but instead of giving fontSize etc. write it under the image (invisible) to enable searchable pdf?

Comment: Is creating an extensive set of metadata tags a viable option? https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/cookbook/workingwithmetadata.html - I'd lean towards something like this instead of polluting the document itself

Comment: How would that make pdf searchable? I wont be able to do Ctl-F and search for keyword to get to that point in the document?

Comment: Well, you didn’t specify how you were doing the search; I thought you were going to run it under your own search engine

Comment: You could write the text invisibly by using text rendering mode 3 ("Neither fill nor stroke text (invisible)"). See `PDPageContentStream.setRenderingMode(RenderingMode.NEITHER)`.

Comment: Thanks Tilman. I am able to add text but running into coordinates issue. For some documents (0,0) seem to be top left corner while others seem to have bottom left. Could that be because those pages are rotated? I am checking rotation using page.getRotation() but it is 0 for all the documents I have tested.

Comment: This shouldn't happen if the fifth parameter of the PDPageContentStream constructor is true... and it is in your code. Alternatively, you could use PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.PREPEND. And make sure you're using the lates version (2.0.16).

Answer (score 0):

There are several libraries that will help you achieve this.

1. Ocrusrex - a simple Python tool to take a PDF, run it through Tesseract 4 OCR and return a searchable PDF. It can be run single-threaded or multithreaded. Full disclosure, this is a small project of mine that I've been working on to do this task with an enterprise favorable license (MIT or Apache licensing instead of GPL or AGPL). You'll need to install Tesseract 4 first.

   Then install the library with

   ```
    pip3 install ocrusrex
   ```

   You could run the tool like this:

   ```
   from OCRUSREX import ocrusrex
   ocrusrex.Multithreaded_OCRPDF(source="Path to source pdf", targetPath="Path to target pdf", verbose=True)
   ```
2. OCRMyPDF - is a standalone tool, written in python, that has more bells and whistles for pre-processing and image correction. I couldn't make it work for my purposes, however, as I wanted a Python library (not a command-line tool) and didn't like that some parts of it have AGPL licensing.

There are some other, maintained tools that just do text extraction. You could also work with some of the python wrappers for tesseract yourself to build your own library.