# how to print text "X" inside box in PDF

Tags: pdf, groovy, pdfbox

i have problem to print text in pdf inside box "WNI "like in that picture

[image]

i already try with this code:

```
def webRootDir = grailsApplication.mainContext.servletContext.getRealPath("/")
        def temp = new File(webRootDir, "/overlayTemp/")
        temp.mkdirs()

        def rdnPage = ("rdnCIMBpage"+_no+".pdf")
        File _page = new File(temp, rdnPage)
        def overlayName = ("overlayCIMB"+_no+".pdf")
        File overlayID = new File(temp, overlayName)

        //load template
        template = assetResourceLocator.findAssetForURI( tpl+_no+".pdf" ).getInputStream()?.bytes
        PDDocument p_doc = PDDocument.load( new ByteArrayInputStream( template ) )
        //log.info("Write "+"CIMB_RDN_Syariah_"+_no+".pdf")
        log.info '[RegistrationService::writeRdnSinarmas][id: ' + registrationInstance.id + '][Write FormRDNSinarmasNew_' + _no + '.pdf]'

        PDDocument overlayDoc = new PDDocument()
        try
        {
            PDPage page = new PDPage()
            overlayDoc.addPage(page)
            PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(overlayDoc, page)
    
            //ininomer1
            //x kalau ditambah akan maju ke kanan
            //y kalau di turunin akan turun ke bawah            
            if(_no==1) {
                if(registrationInstance.personalInformation.citizenship=="WNI"){
                    setText(contentStream, "X", 104, 390)       
                }else{
                    setText(contentStream, "X", 110, 390)
                }
    }
```

how can i print my value "X" inside box WNI?
because now the "X" print behind box, the box is template from PDF file

Comment: thank you for the help, yes that is a form, with box are the template from the pdf, and the "X" is value from the code @K J

Comment: Please share the PDF. If this has acroform fields then use the acroform methods.

Comment: here's the pdf link https://copper-suzann-35.tiiny.site/

Comment: its seem problem with the pdf file, i tried with anoter pdf file it seems work, but i dont know why in this form not working? @TilmanHausherr

Comment: can you tell me what's make the pdf file different each other? @TilmanHausherr

Comment: I don't know how the PDFs are different. Apparantly you're working with overlays. It might happen if the target PDFs have different media sizes. I'll look at your website tonight.

Comment: Your file is a flattened form. What you should do then is either get the original file, or append a content stream instead of using an overlay.

Comment: can u give me example code to modify flattened form like my file? @TilmanHausherr

Comment: I posted a link in the other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36449776/pdfbox-2-0-0-write-text-at-given-postion-in-a-page