# How to put text in rectangle using pdfbox and java/groovy

Tags: java, groovy, pdfbox, pdf-form

Content stream through I wants to show "X" text in the rectangle (the rectangle is from form pdf as default), but the rectangle cover the "X" like this

[image]

I try to get the text "X" in a rectangle in using this code but the rectangle covers the text.

```
 contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(0)
 contentStream.beginText()
 contentStream.newLineAtOffset(104, 390)
 contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(0, 0, 0)
 contentStream.showText("X")
 contentStream.endText()
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of your other question and it has even less info. Here are some examples related to acroform fields https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/2.0/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/interactive/form/

Comment: You just added an annotation. What we really need is the non-flattened form.

Comment: If you can't get the non flattened doc, then read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36449776/pdfbox-2-0-0-write-text-at-given-postion-in-a-page

Comment: how do i can convert from flattened form to non-flattened form? @TilmanHausherr